# How to store a ValidTo date-only DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

We had quite the discussion today on what's the best way to store a `DateTime ValidTo` value. **The value represents a day** on the UI with a date-picker.

E.g. user selects today (03.05.2021). We discussed several options:

- ValidTo 2021-05-03T00:00:00.000Z (z = UTC)

  - because a date has no time
- ValidTo 2021-05-03T23:59:99.999Z

  - because any time on 03.05.2021 should be included
- ValidUntil 2021-05-**04**T00:00:00.000Z

  - because the boundary is clear

I preferred the first idea because to me a date has no time, but how would a consumer of an interface read this? You would always need to know that this DateTime has to be interpreted and validated as a date and not a point in time. Hard to transport that info.

On the other hand: How would you store a date that is not part of a valid-from-to timespan. e.g. `CreatedOn`. Not with any time information if it's just a day, right?

Is it a naming issue?

Are there any best practices? How do you deal with that?

Comment: NodaTime is likely what you want.

Comment: Nah, not sure. At some point I need to send this data out over some interfaces (graphql, json, ...). So it will be iso time again, right?

Comment: @mjwills I doubt NodaTime will help in this case.  It's the same question if the values were ints.   The question is are you doing a less than comparison, or a less than or equal to comparison.

Comment: External systems typically do support dates only -- `2021-05-03` (ISO date) would be the obvious choice of serialization for that (or `2021-05-04` if the boundary is exclusive). This has little bearing on what you use in .NET itself, which would be "whatever is most convenient in your application", including but not limited to custom date-only types if you prefer.

Comment: You should use less than for you validation   So you should use the third choice but also need to check after picker is changed that the date is less than the max date instead of equals.  The format of the date isn't importand since it is really a DateTime object and the visible string is just a format to display results and not the contents of the object,

Comment: When you add time to UI everything gets clear.

Comment: Part of your problem is that you simultaneously talk about storing the value (in some database?) and "consumer of an interface". The internal storage is separate from the presentation format is separate from the allowed input format. Your business layer should translate between the defined/allowed formats for each of those aspects. Ofcourse you can define the accepted input format to be exactly the same as your presentation format, but at least the database storage format should be treated separately.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your input. There are very good and valid points that we combined to the following solution for us:

- Store without time information
- Name "ValidTo**Date**" to transport the information that it's a date and has no time